# Computer doesn't turn off when entering sleep mode

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, suspend

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Y50-70. I am trying to **suspend** my computer by pressing Fn + F1, or by clicking the pause button when the screen is locked. Whenever I do so, the screen will turn black but will remain lit up, also the keyboard LED's are still lit up and the fans don't stop spinning.

I recently updated from 16.04 to 18.04 (Bionic Beaver). But I'm sure that this is not the reason, since **the problem first appeared when I was on 16.04**. (I was hoping that updating to 18.04 would solve the problem)

It will remain in the  described state as long as there is battery power left. This forces me to hold down the power button to shut off.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? Because I'm a fan of not completely shutting of my computer every time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try systemctl suspend in terminal.

Comment: I get the same result when doing that